# Approximate within range Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the general formula needed: `if((b2-b1)=c1,True,False`
However, I need `b2-b1` to approximately equal `c1`, within `5` or so units (in this case seconds). Is there a function that could handle this?

Comment: I assume B1 and B2 are times. Is C1 a time or a whole number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
=ABS(B2-B1-C1)<=5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you:

```
=AND(B2 - B1 >= C1 - 5, B2 - B1 <= C1 + 5)
```

This will return TRUE/FALSE only. You don't need to put IF if you don't want to type expressions.

Comment: I won't add my answer then - is the same, except to say you can use `TIME(0,0,5)` or `0.0000578703703703704` for 5 seconds if stored as date/time format.

Comment: I was about to add another answer using TIME but I assumed Devin just has data in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`=if(and( (b2-b1) >= c1 - 5, (b2-b1) < = c1 + 5 ), true, false)`